# Why does creating an instance of EC2Client segfault using AWS SDK for C++?

Tags: c++, aws-sdk

I am trying to use the AWS SDK for C++. I have a minor sample program which crashes when trying to create an instance of EC2Client.

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/ec2/EC2Client.h>
#include <aws/ec2/model/DescribeInstancesRequest.h>
#include <aws/ec2/model/DescribeInstancesResponse.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
    Aws::EC2::EC2Client ec2;    
    Aws::EC2::Model::DescribeInstancesRequest request;
    return 0;
}
```

The program segfaults on the line `Aws::EC2::EC2Client ec2;` but I cannot seem to figure out why.

I have tried to link my application towards both shared libs of libaws-`cpp-sdk-core` and `cpp-sdk-ec2` aswell has statically linked. So it seems to be related to something else.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to start using any new toolkit with reading its manual.

All code using the AWS SDK and C++ should have at least the following:

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
...

Aws::SDKOptions options;
Aws::InitAPI(options);

// use the sdk

Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
```